# Saved items are empty when retrieving at a later point

Tags: c#, database, xamarin, sqlite-net-extensions, sqlite.net

I am using Xamarin and C# to make a cross-platform app. SQLite.Net Extensions are being used for the local database. The User table contains a list of registers, as seen below:

```
public class User
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }      
    //public ObservableCollection<Register> registerList { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(RegStudent))]
    public ObservableCollection<Register> Registers { get; set; } 

    public User()
    {
        this.Registers = new ObservableCollection<Register>();
    }

    public void addRegisterAccess(Register register)
    {
        Registers.Add(register);
    }
}
```

When a register is made, it is added to the register table, then added to this list, done as below:

```
//Set the register to the updated version of this register that is stored on db, 
//as current register that has been created through user input does not have an ID.
register = database.db.GetRegisterByNameAndLocation(register.Name, register.Location);

//Add the register to the current user list of registers. Then fetch the new info and set the current user
// from the db.
database.db.GetUserByEmail(currentUser.user.emailAddress).addRegisterAccess(register);
```

When I try to access the list of registers, through the user object, it says the list does not contain any elements.

I have looked around for solutions and they seem to mention the SQLite `UpdateWithChildren`, but this method is not one that exists in my SQLite Connection or in my db. The list of registers is a `ManyToMany` relationship, how does the update fit into all of this?

**EDIT: ** I have now got the update method, but seem to be getting an exception when it is hit. Below is the method in my 'DatabaseManager' that adds a register to a user list:

```
public void addRegisterAccess(User user, Register register)
    {
        user.Registers.Add(register);
        _connection.InsertOrReplaceWithChildren(user, true);
    }
```

The exception below is given when a register is added, I thought the code to link the classes (using intermediate table) did not need to be called by user code?

```
    02-10 12:09:51.662 E/AndroidRuntime( 4461): Caused by: md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable: SQLiteNetExtensions.Exceptions.IncorrectRelationshipException: User.Registers: ManyToMany relationship origin must have a foreign key defined in the intermediate type
02-10 12:09:51.662 E/AndroidRuntime( 4461):   at SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions.WriteOperations.Assert (Boolean assertion, System.Type type, System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property, System.String message) <0xd84bb6e8 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
02-10 12:09:51.662 E/AndroidRuntime( 4461):   at SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions.WriteOperations.UpdateManyToManyForeignKeys (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn, System.Object element, System.Reflection.PropertyInfo relationshipProperty) <0xd84b9750 + 0x0026b> in <filename unknown>:0 
02-10 12:09:51.662 E/AndroidRuntime( 4461):   at SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions.WriteOperations.UpdateInverseForeignKeys (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn, System.Object element) <0xd84b9578 + 0x0014f> in <filename unknown>:0 
02-10 12:09:51.662 E/AndroidRuntime( 4461):   at SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions.WriteOperations.UpdateWithChildren (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn, System.Object element) <0xd84b8a68 + 0x0003b> in <filename unknown>:0 
02-10 12:09:51.662 E/AndroidRuntime( 4461):   at SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions.WriteOperations.InsertWithChildrenRecursive (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn, System.Object element, Boolean replace, Boolean recursive, ISet`1 objectCache) <0xd84b76f8 + 0x000af> in <filename unknown>:0 
02-10 12:09:51.662 E/AndroidRuntime( 4461):   at SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions.WriteOperations.InsertOrReplaceWithChildren (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn, System.Object element, Boolean recursive) <0xd84b76a8 + 0x0002f> in <filename unknown>:0 
02-10 12:09:51.662 E/AndroidRuntime( 4461):   at RegistrationApp.Data.DatabaseManager.addRegisterAccess (RegistrationApp.User user, RegistrationApp.Models.Register register) <0xd84b7578 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
02-10 12:09:51.662 E/AndroidRuntime( 4461):   at RegistrationApp.CreateRegisterPage+<OnCreateButtonClicked>d__1b.MoveNext () <0xd87ad788 + 0x006c3> in <filename unknown>:0 
02-10 12:09:51.662 E/AndroidRuntime( 4461): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Just to add, my intermediate table class looks like this:

```
public class RegUser
    {
        [ForeignKey(typeof(User))]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(typeof(Register))]
        public int RegisterID { get; set; }
    }
```

**EDIT: ** Below is the Register Class itself:

```
public class Register
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int RegisterID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string StartTime { get; set; }
        public string EndTime { get; set; }
        public Boolean Recurring { get; set; }

        [ManyToMany(typeof(RegStudent), "StudentID", "Registers")]
        public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<Student, string>> StudentList { get; set; }

        [ManyToMany(typeof(RegUser), "UserID", "Registers")]
        public ObservableCollection<User> UserList { get; set; }

        public Register()
        {
            this.StudentList = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<Student, string>>();
            this.UserList = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        }

        //Adds a student to the Student List for this register, marking the string value as '-', to show the register has not been taken yet.
        //This value will be set to the status of the student, to show them as Present, AWOL, Sick, Late, etc.
        public void addStudent(Student student)
        {
            StudentList.Add(new KeyValuePair<Student, string>(student, "-"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try adding `using SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions;` to make `UpdateWithChildren` method available.

Comment: @redent84 Cannot believe I missed that. I have used the method but it is giving out an exception I haven't seen before. I have updated to question to show the code and exception.

Comment: @redent84 I was trying to use `InsertOrUpdateWithChildren` but tried to use `UpdateWithChildren` instead. I am now getting a different exception, one that says ` SQLiteNetExtensions.Exceptions.IncorrectRelationshipException: Register.StudentList: ManyToMany relationship destination must have Primary Key`... the only solution I could find online did not help to resolve this. Any idea where I should be looking to prevent the excpetion? Thanks for the help

Comment: Does your `Register` class have a `PrimaryKey`?

Comment: @redent84 It does, it's a `[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]` `public int RegisterID { get; set; }`.

Comment: Try adding a `PrimaryKey` to `RegUser`

Comment: @redent84 I have added a PrimaryKey (an auto incrementing one to `RegUser` and `RegStudent`, but I still get the exception saying `Register.StudentList: ManyToMany relationship destination must have Primary Key`, when trying to add a register to a user list.

Comment: Can you post your `Register` code? The issue is probably there

Comment: @redent84 added the `Register` code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a list of `KeyValuePair` and thus getting the error that `KeyValuePair` has no primary key:

```
[ManyToMany(typeof(RegStudent), "StudentID", "Registers")]
public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<Student, string>> StudentList { get; set; }
```

Change it to a list of `Student`:

```
[ManyToMany(typeof(RegStudent), "StudentID", "Registers")]
public ObservableCollection<Student> StudentList { get; set; }
```

If you need to store information in the relation, you should store it in `RegUser` class:

```
public class RegUser
{
    [ForeignKey(typeof(User))]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Register))]
    public int RegisterID { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Be aware that SQLite-Net Extensions currently doesn't support additional properties in intermediate tables and you'll have to fetch that information manually:

```
var regUser = conn.Table<RegUser>.Where(ru => ru.UserID == user.ID && ru.RegisterID == register.ID).FirstOrDefault();
if (regUser != null) {
    var status = regUser.Status;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it fixes the exception problem completely. However, the original problem of lists being empty even though items have been added still exists. I have tried using `UpdateWithChildren(register)` and also tried `InsertOrReplaceWithChildren(register)`, at the time of creation of a student or register, but the lists still does not show anything.

Comment: I've had a further look at the way in which I am adding items to the database, it seems the items are added correctly, but the lists are always empty. Is there a specific way to add items to a `SQLiteNetExtensions`  object list?

Comment: If they are added correctly to the database, maybe you are not retrieving them. To fetch relationships you have to use any of the `WithChildren` fetch methods or use `GetChildren` method later on the object.

Comment: Ah, I was using the `Table` method from an example based on `SQLite.Net`, not the Extensions. The list is now being populated without any exceptions. Tanks